# ngFocus Bugged on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da100gu5/).

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" step="1" ng-focus="logFocus()"/>
```

When clicking on the step arrows of the input, the focus is logged in Chrome/Safari/Opera (haven't checked IE), but on Firefox nothing happens.

Am I missing something or is this bugged ?

Comment: Because the focus isn't set on the input, at least in Firefox, when you use the step arrows. Add another text input beside to convince you.

Comment: I know, my question is why in FF clicking the arrows is not considered to be focused.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this ?

Comment: @Aditi Not really, in my case switching the ng-focus to ng-change made more sense anyway so I was lucky enough to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onfocus event doesn't fire on your case because the arrows in FF are not attached to the input element, but they attached to the body of the document.

Look at this test code: 
html ->

```
<div class="test">
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" value="1" id="test1" />  <br>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" value="1" id="test2" /> 
</div>
```

Jquery ->

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
       console.log($(document.activeElement));
    });
});
```

After running this code in chrome and touching the arrows I got the following element in the console :

```
[input#test1, context: input#test1]
```

But when i run this code in FF, i get the following element ->

```
Object { 0: <body>, context: <body>, length: 1 }
```

As you can see, when you click on the arrows the focus get to the their container (in FF this is the body). Therefore your event didn't work.

Link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ah2nca/).

Comment: I'd say that's a weird implementation by FF :)

Comment: _"the arrows in FF are not attached to the input element"_ - Even your own test disagrees. The focus just stays where it is. Your answer needs to be fixed.